# Use of "for all" in definition of reflexive and symmetric relations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

My book says that a relation *R* on *A* is

1. *reflexive*, if $\ (a,a) \in R, \  for\ every \ a \in A$
2. *symmetric*, if $\ (a_1,a_2) \in R \implies (a_2,a_1) \in R,\ for\ all\ a_1,a_2 \in A$

Although I *know* what a symmetric relation is, I can't understand the formal definition. My interpretation of definition 2 is that because of the "for all", all the ordered pairs should be a part of *R*, in other words 
$R = A \times A $ which is obviously wrong.

So, my question is that why is the "for all" present in the 2nd definition? Also, do "for all" and "for every" suggest different things in the definition?

Comment: I am not well-versed in logic but I would say the quantifier in the second statement is superfluous. And hence your interpretation of the definition is also false.

Comment: I agree, the quantifier seems to be superfluous. Nonetheless, this is to be read as follows: $R$ is symmetric if for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $(a_1,a_2)$ is in $R$, we also have that $(a_2,a_1)$ is in $R$. So the second condition is to be read as a condition on all $a_1, a_2$ which satisfy $(a_1,a_2)\in R$.

Comment: @Ishfaaq : I agree with you in the sense that if (a1,a2) is in R, then doesn't it automatically imply that a1 and a2 are in A.

Comment: That is not the path of reasoning you should take. Check out Oliver's comment. He has put it very clearly. What do you think?

Comment: @OliverBraun: Yes, thank you. Now it makes sense. I was just confused because everywhere the above definition was included including wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement should be read as:

> For all $a_1, a_2 \in A$: If $(a_1, a_2) \in R \Rightarrow (a_2, a_1) \in R$

Hence we don't consider all pairs $(a_1, a_2) \in A$, only $(a_1, a_2) \in R$. However, every element $a_i \in A$ may be used to "try" to form these pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of quantifiers can be confusing sometimes.
A clearer way to phrase these definitions would be to put the "for all" expression before the conclusion. The new definitions would look like this:

> 1. A relation $R$ is reflexive if for all $a\in A$, $(a,a)\in R$.
> 2. A relation $R$ is symmetric if for all $a_1,a_2\in A$, $(a_1,a_2)\in R\implies(a_2,a_1)\in R$.

As to your second question, "for any", "for every", and "for all" mean the same thing in mathematics, although the clearest is probably "for all".